# How to solve the issue of multiple ImageView in android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, url, imageview

I am developing an application.

Which requires Multiple ImageView in the GridView Layout. When user click on ImageView the Image should open in next activity in full screen.

My problem is when I load multiple ImageView in the screen it doesn't Load. But when I click on any Images it Load Successfully in new Window. Because all the data is running through web-service.

Is there any solution for that?

My Graphical Layout is:

[image: Thats Layout of multiple ImageView of the screen]

How can I load all the Image URL row wise to reduce the load on server?
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Its happening because all the images load at the same time so emulator cant load all the images at the same time at increase the load.